# What's causing Expo's ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync() to crash the app on some android devices?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I have a managed expo app that uses expo SDK 39 and expo image picker ("expo-image-picker": "~9.1.0") currently in production. Some android users have reported the camera feature "not working" which makes a call to ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync(). I have been able to reproduce it on a Nexus S Emulator running android 10, the whole app crashes. No error messages are logged.

I thought that the issue was specific to Android 10, however some users reported the issue on Android 11 (and android 8).

I tried wrapping a try-catch block to pull out an error, with no luck, the app still crashes, and no logs.

I also tried making a dummy app with only the above functionality in question, however I get the same results on the Nexus S emulator: The app crashes, no reports logged.

Here is an example of the function call which is triggering the crashes.

```js
const takeImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
      base64: true,
    });
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      console.log(result.uri);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: A solution is found here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/18760 (Adding imagemanipulator)

The issue is discussed on github https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7946.

It appears that the following note in the [expo docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v39.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickergetpendingresultasync) refers to the issue:

```
Note: Make sure that you handle MainActivity destruction on Android. See ImagePicker.getPendingResultAsync.
```

However, the docs seem to be describing handling a crash occuring *after* taking a picture. The crashing described in the question occurs immediately upon calling imagePicker's camera method.